# Match Cell in One Column and Not Match in Other Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 columns in excel. I want to compare the cells in column A to column B and C. If cell A1, matches with column $B:$B but not column $C:$C. I want to return A1 in Column D. How do I do this??

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you tried so far? What is the data format; date, numeric or text?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an `If/And` statement should work for you. I did a test on the following formula entered in column D and it seems to return what you are looking for:

`=IF(AND(A1=$B:$B,A1<>$C:$C),A1,"")`

This exact formula would return a blank (not Null) value for those fields that don't meet either criteria, so if you want it to return a text string or number, enter that value instead of the quotation marks "".

Comment: Well said and to the point. I just adjusted formatting a little, but other than that, good answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is a "good" answer? Is that formula supposed to be array-entered, to give a test of those conditions against the entire 2 million-plus cells in those columns? Even if it is array-entered, there is no function which is further acting upon this array to determine how many of those tests are TRUE: in fact, only the result of the test against the very first cells in those ranges, i.e. whether A1=B1 and A1<>C1, will be considered. The other 2 million-plus tests are redundant as far as this construction is concerned. And if it's NOT array-entered, well, you're even further away...

Comment: @XOR LX Are you sure it needs to be any more complicated than it is? The question seems to refer to a fairly simple data set, in which case this formula should provide accurate answers, without being array-entered.

Comment: Why are entire columns being referenced? If the formula is intended to be placed in D1 and then dragged down, it should be: IF(AND(A1=B1,A1<>C1),A1,"").

Comment: @XOR LX I may have misunderstood the user's intent, but it seems like the goal was to compare A1 to all data in column B and then the same with column C, not just A1 to B1 and C1. This can be done without an array using the formula given above. I agree that the ranges could also be defined as an array, but with such a simple data set, why complicate the formula if it is unnecessary?

Comment: "Without an array"? Try going through your formula using the Evaluate Formula feature. You'll see that only the very first cells in columns B and C are passed for consideration to the IF function: all other two million-plus cells aren't even considered. Excel simply doesn't work as you imagine.